# Replacing Dilettante power with a level 13 encounter power

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, half-elf

My players just hit level 13 and get to replace one old encounter attack power with a new level 13 power.
Is there any reason why a half-elf player couldn't choose to replace his Dilettante power?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You cannot replace your Dilettante power with a class encounter power.**

When you gain your level 13 encounter power, it can replace any of your *class* encounter powers. Your Dilettante power, despite being useable only once per encounter, is neither an encounter power nor a class power.

From PHB1, pg27, Powers (emphasis mine):

> ... At 13th, 17th, 23rd, and 27th levels, you can replace any **encounter** attack power you know **from your class** with a new one of your level (or an encounter attack power of a lower level, if you choose).

From PHB1, pg27, Half-Elves (*emphasis mine*):

> **Dilettante:** At 1st level, you choose an *at-will* power from a class different from yours. You can use that power *as* an encounter power.

Your Dilettante power is neither an encounter attack power nor a power from your class, so it cannot be replaced by your level 13 power.

Comment: Can i also replace Paragon path power?

Comment: @GuardNo.67: Only by taking the Reserve Maneuver feat.